# How to have multiple paths display URL as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want `users#new` and `tasks#index` to display as the root path URL, i.e. `/` When a user logs in on the path `users#new` (set as root) they are redirected to `tasks#index` and URL does not change. Can this be done in the routes.rb file?

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Todo::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :sessions 
  resources :subscriptions
  resources :users
  resources :tasks do
    collection do
      post :sort
    end
  end
  root :to => "users#new"
  match "sessions#new" => "tasks#index"
  match "sessions#" => "tasks#index"
```

Comment: You may be fighting best practices and the Rails way here. Rails apps are not typically done using a "FrontController" approach like you're describing. If you want to leverage learning resources, gems, etc. you might try to work with the framework rather than against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I would actually do this,but assuming you map the root tasks#index, you could also use a before filter to render the sessions#new template when the user is not logged in:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authorize_access

  def authorize_access
    unless logged_in?
      render :template => 'sessions/new'
      return false  #I don't remember if you need this still or not
    end
  end

  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

end
```

To be clear, when a user requests "/", Rails will route this request to a single controller and action. You can map multiple paths to the same controller/action, but a single path is deterministic to a particular controller/action. IOW - it is not logically possible in routes to have a get request for any path, root or otherwise, go to more than one controller/action.

Users don't see a controller and action though, they see the result of what the action renders, usually based on some template, and that you can determine in the action (or a controller filter's) logic, as I did above.

You could also create a 3rd controller, a RootController, that contains the logic to display the list of tasks or a login page based on if the user is logged in.

Comment: Andrew this could work, if I did this though, I would want `sessions#new` to display as `root` –– `sessions#new` and `tasks#index` to display as `root` regardless of path. Thoughts?

Comment: Your question is flawed.  One action on one controller can be designated as root, that is just how routes work in rails, but what it displays can be either a login page, or a list of tasks. The above achieves that end.

Comment: Another way to think about this is to create a HomeController, and have it be set as root, and this could delegate to either the sessions#new or items#index template, but not actually map those actions with their own route. My above solution achieves the same thing, and if you never map sessions#new to its own route, or if a user requests /sessions/new have it redirect to root, you get the behavior you seem to be asking for.

Comment: Cool, I tried it. When I load the page, the root path is getting "localhost:3000/users/new" which is the action and controller, where previously it was "localhost:3000". Is there a way to have localhost:3000 for both users/new and /tasks/?

Answer (score 1):

I have just found routes definitions by constraints

in your routes.rb file

```
class LoggedInConstraint
  def initialize(value)
     ...
  def matches?(request)
      request.cookies.key?("user_token") == @value
    end
  end
end

RedmineApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "static#home", :constraints => LoggedInConstraint.new(false)
  root :to => "users#show", :constraints => LoggedInConstraint.new(true)
  ....
end
```

It's described here:
http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/05/31/user-centric-routing-in-rails-3/